# akka.net scaling in azure asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, akka.net

I have set up Akka.net actors running inside an ASP.net application to handle some asynchronous & lightweight procedures. I'm wondering how Akka scales when I scale out the website on Azure. Let's say that in code I have a single actor to process messages of type FooBar.  When I have two instances of the website, is there still a single actor or are there now two actors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, whenever you'll call `ActorOf` method, you'll order creation of a new actor instance. If you'll call that in two actor systems, you'll end up with two separate actors, having the same relative paths inside their systems, but different global addresses.

There are several ways to share an information about actors between actor systems:

1. When using `Akka.Remote` you can call actors living on another actor system given their [addresses](http://getakka.net/articles/concepts/addressing.html) or `IActorRef`s. Requirements:

   - You must know the path to a given actor.
   - You must know the actual address (URL or IP) of an actor system, on which that actor lives.
   - Both actor systems must be able to communicate via TCP between actor system (i.e. open ports on firewall).
2. When using `Akka.Cluster` actor systems (also known as nodes) can form a cluster. They will exchange information about their localization in the network, track incoming nodes and eventually detect a dead or unreachable ones. On top of it, you can use higher level components i.e. [cluster routers](http://getakka.net/articles/clustering/cluster-routing.html). Requirements:

   - Every node must be able to open TCP channel to every other (so again, firewalls etc.)
   - A new incoming node must know at least one node that is already part of the cluster. This is easily achievable as part of the pattern known as lighthouse or via plugins and 3rd party services like consul.
   - All nodes must have the same name.
3. Finally, when using cluster configuration you can make use of [Akka.Cluster.Sharding](https://petabridge.com/blog/introduction-to-cluster-sharding-akkadotnet/) - it's essentially a higher level abstraction over actor's location inside the cluster. When using it, you don't need to explicitly tell, where to find or when to create an actor. Instead, all you need is a unique actor identifier. When sending a message to such actor, it will be created ad-hoc somewhere in the cluster if it didn't exist before, and rebalanced to equally spread the workload in cluster. This plugin also handles all logic associated with routing the message to that actor.

Comment: Thanks for the great info. It sounds like the answer is that there will be two actorsystems and two actors if there are two instances of the site. However, how are the actorsystems distinguished from each other? I have code in global.asax that creates a new actorsystem like so `ActorSystem.Create("name")`, if this code runs for each instance, it will use the same name.

Comment: One of the requirements of akka clusters is, that all actor systems must have the same name. If you read the doc about addressing I've put in my answer, you'll see that name is only one of the many components consisting inside actor system path. Usually the different part of addresses is URL/IP and port.

Comment: @user1715925 did you have any luck scaling using Akka.Cluster on an Azure App Service? I am not entirely sure if, or if not an App Service supports the mentionedn requirements (opening TCP channels, firewalls)...